# How to display four images with rotate effect from folder using classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have one folder in which my images get stored, now I want to create a slideshow such as the one [here](http://www.simplyapples.com/catalog/).

I tried the following code (but it displays just single image on page refresh):

```vb
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<html>
<head>
    <%
    Function RandomImage(strPath,strDefault)
        On Error Resume Next
        'response.Write("HI")
        Randomize Timer

        ' declare all variables
        Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFiles, objFile
        Dim strFiles, strImages, strPhysical, strFile

        ' this constant has the names of valid image file name
        ' extensions and can be modified for more image types
        Const strValid = ".gif.jpg.png"

        ' make sure we have a trailing slash in the path
        If Right(strPath,1) <> Chr(47) Then strPath = strPath & Chr(47)
        ' get the physical path of the folder
        strPhysical = Server.MapPath(strPath)

        ' get a File System Object
        Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        ' create a folder object
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPhysical)

        ' get the files collection
        Set objFiles = objFolder.Files

        ' enumerate the files collection looking for images
        For Each objFile in objFiles    
            strFile = LCase(objFile.Name)
            If Instr(strValid,Right(strFile,4)) Then
                ' add vaild images to a string of image names
                strFiles = strFiles & strFile & vbTab
            End If
        Next

        ' split the image names into an array
        strImages = Split(strFiles,vbTab)

        ' if we have an array...
        If UBound(strImages) > 1 Then
            ' get a random name
            RandomImage = strPath & strImages(Int(Rnd(1)*UBound(strImages)))
        Else
            ' otherwise return the default
            RandomImage = strDefault
        End If
    End Function
    %>

    <%
    strImg = RandomImage("./retailers/","./retailers/A1-Supplements.jpg")

    strsplit = split(strImg,"/")  
    ' Response.Write(strsplit(2)) 
    '   Response.Write("rahul =" &strImg)
    ' d_desc    = Split(Request.Form("strImg"),"/")

    ' Name of text file to search:
    strFileName = "saveimagename.txt"

    ' Text to search for:
    strSearchText = strsplit(2)

    'response.Write(strSearchText)&"<br/>"
    'response.end()

    ' Create an instance of the the File System Object
    Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Open the file
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(strFileName))

    URLString = ""
    Do While Not objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
        strReadLineText = objTextFile.ReadLine
        'response.Write(strReadLineText & "<br>")

        If strReadLineText<>"" then
            If Instr(strReadLineText,",")>0 then
                strReadLineTextArr=split(strReadLineText,",")
                URLString=strReadLineTextArr(1)
            end if 
        end if  

        If  InStr(lcase(strReadLineText), lcase(strSearchText)) > 0 Then 
            Exit Do
        End If   
    Loop

    strSearchText=""

    ' Close and release file references
    objTextFile.Close

    Set objTextFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    'Response.Write URLString
    'Response.End()
    %>
</head>

<body>
    <div align="center" style="width:800px; float:left;">
        <center>
            <table border="0" width="800px">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#000" align="center" style="border:none;">
                        <a href="<%=URLString%>" target="_blank"><img src="<%=strImg%>" onClick="<%=URLString%>" border="0"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Try to accomplish this from the server-side is very difficult. You can only assign the images once and the only way to change them is for your user to refresh the page.
What you need to do is create your slideshow on the client-side with JavaScript. Fortunately, there are lots of libraries that can help you. Search for slideshows and jquery and you should be able to find what you need. [Here's one such link](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/08/25-jquery-image-galleries-and-slideshow-plugins/).

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to do this on the client side using jQuery.  It will be more efficient for your end users and less server interaction.

Here are a few good slideshows with tutorials on how to implement them:

http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/